# This question is asked in a coding test. I am unable to find the solution till now

Tags: arrays, algorithm

An array of integer is given of size n. We have to make all the equal. For this we can add 1, 2 or 5 to the array element any time and to any element. We have to find minimum no of operation to do so?

For example
Array.  2 2 3 7

Output should be 2

Explanation
In first operation we add 1 to 2,2,7
After that array will be as  3 3 3 8
Now in 2nd operation we add 5 to 3,3,3
After that array will be as 8,8,8,8

Comment: Please show us your attempt at this.  Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, but we would be happy to help you get your code working.

Comment: Your title says, "till now".  So you found it?  Or did you mean, "so far" instead of "till now"?

Comment: FWIW, there is not a single question mark in your post.  After you've described the coding test, please ask a clear question.  (I assume you want the *minimum*, and proof it's minimum) . Thanks.

Comment: I just want a approach to solve.

Comment: I don't want code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first think about how many operations it would cost to get all values to the highest value in the list.

In a second step you can think if there could be a better solution if you try to reach highest-value+1, highest-value+2, highest-value+3, highest-value+4 .